# Does Microsoft recommend blocking port 25?

Tags: asp.net, server, port, exchange-server

We are asp.net developers, work in a company.
Development achieved in our development devices/laptops where VS installed. 
After development, test operations finished, we publish application into servers.
Our applications need to send emails, so we do that via exchange server through port 25.

Suddenly, during development and test stage, we noticed that we cannot send emails. We contacted exchange server administrator. He told us that he blocked port 25 for our development devices/laptops because Microsoft recommends that.

We asked him how we can achieve development, test operations? He said that you can do that from server! Note that server is for just publishing; it does not have any IDE for developing or test!

Is this true?
Does Microsoft recommend this?

Comment: So you can't send email from your computers? Because that's what blocking port 25 means. What do you use for email then? And no, MS doesn't recommend that email be blocked from developer machines. Does the administrator have a reference for this, or is this hearsay, like many other similar recommendations?

Comment: On the other hand, Exchange may be set up to require SSL/TLS, in which case it doesn't use port 25. So does, eg, GMail's SMTP server. That *is* indeed a recommendation - require encrypted connections from *anyone*. That's why you need to use port 465 (SSL) or 587 (TLS) with GMail

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos. So, Asking developers to test from server not from developer machines is not practical, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not true. But it is recommended, not to allow anonymous smtp access to Exchange Server.
So there should be a (named) connector for your application on port 25, which is requiring TLS and authentication, which means, your application needs to implement smtp authentication.
In that scenario, the Mailbox you are authenticating with should be monitored for NDRs.

Comment: Thanks Martin, he can allow developer machines and lock for anonymous. Isn't this practical? and you see Asking developers to test from server not from developer machines is not practical, don't you?

Comment: No, because developers clients normally get their IPs dynamically by a dhcp service like any other client on the network, so he cant setup the connector with fixed (client) ips. With servers he can, because servers usually use static ip configuration.

Comment: Developers have static IPs. Do you see development/test stage can be achieved on server?

Comment: You should address that to your Systems Administrator :)